# Calling ASP pages within ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

Scenario : On a ASP.NET site, we have a login page (login.aspx).

Within login.aspx.cs based on the person who logs in, sometimes we need to redirect to an ASP page. Currently these ASP pages are on a different site (old ASP site) but I want to copy over 3 ASP pages within the ASP.NET site. Is it possible? Can I create a new virtual directory (or just directory) and place these ASP pages?

OR

Do I need to have these ASP pages stay where they are and from ASP.NET  site (login.aspx.cs) I will need to issue Response.Redirect to that old ASP site?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your <s>.net application</s> (I should say) IIS will still execute the asp classic pages, however asp.net and asp classic do not share session variables. I had to write two in between pages that converted asp.net session values down to asp classic and vice versa for an application I was working on with a similar situation.

Comment: I am not looking at session variables at this moment and I guess I may need to later. I would like to copy the ASP page and call within ASP.NET site.The only change I would do to ASP page is changing the header or images. Below are my comments that I posted to Jelle. thanks.

Comment: you do care about sessions. you are talking about using a login.aspx page. unless you setup is not using sessions for logins (which I doubt) the asp classic page will not think the user is logged in if you check a session var for it. means your pages will be insecure. you probably need to check the IIS setup to make sure the asp pages will execute.

Comment: thanks for your inputs and I will consider them and also check. But meanwhile I tried to redirect to contactus.asp (static ASP page) from ASP.NET site. The contactus.asp is also copied within ASP.NET site. However I get errors saying "this type of page is not served". Is there anything else to take care of?

Comment: I just tried a test.asp page inside of one of my MVC application and it works just fine. does your asp page execute in any other websites? if your contactus.asp page doesn't care if the user is logged in then you shouldn't have to worry about the session.

Comment: Now I am getting "Page can not be found" whereas the page actually exists. This is what I did. I created new folder under my ASP.NET project named TEST. Within Test folder, I copied Contactus.asp. I then put in login.aspx.cs Response.Redirect("~\\Test\\contactus.asp");. I get 'The page cannot be found'. I then put contactus.pdf and redirect works opening the PDF file. Is there any other way to copy ASP file to the ASP.NET project and call ASP page? thanks

Comment: why do you have a double slash? Try redirecting to the complete path e.g. `http://company.com/test/contactus.asp`.

Comment: I figured out something. I did with your idea of putting whole path but what turns out is that the contents of ASP page is something not working. For example I removed all contents of ASP page and just "hello world" and it loaded the page. But if I put the contents back, same error repeats.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can redirect to pages outside your own application/website, but you can copy the pages from the other website to your own website. From your login page, you can then redirect to the appropriate page in your own application/website. If you copy the pages, it might be a good idea to change the old namespace of the pages to a namespace suitable for your own application/website

Comment: This is what I am trying to do. What I did was created a new folder in my ASP.NET as "TestASP" and placed 3 ASP pages from that ASP site. I then went to login.aspx.cs and issued a response.redirect to one of the ASP pages (within the ASP.NET site). 
However I get the following error 

This type of page is not served.
Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.asp' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: Have you tried .aspx instead of .asp? That's the only error I can come up with at the moment.